# Reading HDF files and Converting them into Binary in Bash/Mac command line

Tags: python, hdf5

I am having trouble downloading hdf files from a directory in an ssh server and opening with HDFView 3.0 on Mac.

I used the sftp to connect to the server and then navigated to the directory with the files using the Terminal. Afterwards I did
mget *.hdf to download all the files. However, the files cannot be opened in the HDFView.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: You realize HDF5 _**is**_ a binary file format, right? What kind of binary file format do you want (instead of HDF5), and why? Have you written any code to open the file and access the datasets? Just about any SO question tagged `[h5py]` shows the function calls. Datasets are read as NumPy arrays.

Comment: @kcw78 I am supposed to read in all the hdf5 files containing the FPAR data using bash and then extract the data which is stored in different sizes/bits and save them in binary format then remap them to long projection. And I'm not sure the code to do so. My adviser said to download HDFViewer to see the structure of the data but still having trouble with that since it's not compatible with Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is for coding questions. To get started, you need to understand HDF5 and the the data schema for FPAR. Begin with "Introduction to HDF5" at the HDF Group: [Learning HDF5](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Learning%20HDF5). Once you understand groups and datasets, there are several ways to view the schema:

1. **HDFView**: There is a MacOS build for 3.0 "Release 1". You need to create a (free) account with The HDF Group and login to access it. Ref: [HDFView Downloads](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/)
2. **h5dump** utility: This is a command line utility. I think you need to install HDF5 to get it. Ref: [HDF5 Downloads](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/)
3. **ptdump** utility: This is a command line utility that is part of PyTables package (aka tables).
4. You can also use Python packages **h5py** or **PyTables** to open and query the file for basic schema info (the group and dataset names and contents).

You will have to invest some time before you start coding. This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I was able to download the HDFView 2.14 which was the only one that seems to have the option for MacOs download. Since I have to open the HDF file to view the data, how do I download hdf5 files from a ssh server in bash? Is it possible to save the datasets onto my computer or can I access them somewhere?

Comment: Be careful with HDFView 2.14; it was built with HDF5 1.8.19, so won't support recently created files. If you create a login you can access the MacOS build for 3.0 "Release 1". It was built with HDF5 1.10.3. (Current HDFView version is built with HDF5-1.10.7, and current HDF5 version is 1.12). You will have to work with files "on" your computer (could be a remote file system w/ a local mount point). Downloading files from a ssh server in bash is a different question. Have you solved that yet? Short answer: use `wget [options] url Google to get the option flags.

Comment: I was able to download all the files using the sftp and get command however I could not open the files. Whenever, I try to open the files in the HDFView, an error message pops up. What could be the reason? Could it be because the file version is different?